# How to preselect a template in OTRS

Tags: otrs

I am currently working on customising OTRS5 and I have added a new option to the navigation bar that when clicked takes the user to the 'Create new ticket' page with the queue and template already populated (using the Dest and TemplateID URL parameters).

However, although the text template has been selected by the TemplateID parameter, the Javascript that fills the actual text body does not fire and the text field remains blank.

Is there a way to also prepopulate the text field with the text in the template?

Thanks in advance :)